# Is there any tool in Ruboto like ProMotion in RubyMotion?

Tags: android, rubymotion, ruboto, rubymotion-promotion

I know there are many tools/frameworks in [RubyMotion](http://rubymotion.com), such as: [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap), [AFMotion](https://github.com/usepropeller/afmotion). (refer to: http://siwei.me/blog/posts/rubymotion-2-must-have-libraries-for-rubymotion-part2 ) , but when I googled around for the similar tools in Ruboto (Ruby on Android) I didn't see any result.

Could someone give me a clue? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few (none?) Ruboto-specific libraries that I know of, but you can use all the Android tools and libraries in addition to all Java tools and libraries that do not target Java 7/8 or JNI, and you can use all pure Ruby gems, and gems targeting JRuby.

Ruboto itself is bundled with ruboto/widget which is a DSL for creating UI layouts.

Comment: could you please tell me the name of the Ruboto-specific libs you know?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Calabash-Android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) is automation tool using Ruby. Do you need automation tool or tools that helps writing native application in Android?

Comment: thanks @Bapu, what I need is the Ruboto-specific libs, but not automation tools using Ruby.  thanks again.